# How to compare a string of times against an event time in Android?

Tags: java, android, jsoup

I'm trying to use jsoup to capture a list of arrival times for a train at a particular station from my city's transportation website.

Using jsoup's `getElementById` method, I've been able to return a large string of arrival times, given like this:

`7:00 7:30 8:00 8:30 9:00 9:30 ...`

I want to compare these arrival times against a scheduled event. So, for this example, if a user had an appointment at 8:45, I'd want to return *only* the arrival time `8:30`.

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have the String `7:00 7:30 8:00 8:30 9:00 9:30 ...`

If you must use Strings, I came up with the following code that might help you achieve your end result:

```
int apptHour = 8, apptMin = 45; // appointment is 8:45

String arrivalTime = ""; // temp var to store latest acceptable arrival time

String times = "7:00 7:30 8:00 8:30 9:00 9:30"; 
String[] time = times.split(" "); // split your string "7:00 7:30 8:00" etc.

for (String s : time) {
    String[] parts = s.split(":"); // split each time into hours and mins

    // if appointment is on the hour, remove 1 minute so that we calculate the correct arrival
    if (apptMin == 0) { apptHour--; apptMin = 59; }

    if (Integer.parseInt(parts[0]) == apptHour) {
        if (Integer.parseInt(parts[1]) < apptMin) {
            arrivalTime = parts[0] + ":" + parts[1]; 
        }
    }
}
System.out.println(arrivalTime);
```

So for this example it will print `8:30` as the recommended arrival time for an appointment at `8:45`. If you have an appointment at `8:00`, it would recommend `7:30` as the arrival time, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

`String#split(String)` the `String` with a delimiter of a space and compare each value to the appointment time.

Comment: Would I need to cast the time as a Date? I thought strings can only be compared in terms of length, position of a character, etc.?

Comment: You can't cast the time as a `Date` because it's a `String`. But yes, you're right about comparing strings.